# Order of execution of nested views

Tags: oracle

According to the example I wrote, which will be executed first? Will it select all records from Table1 in QueryView1 and be filtered in QueryView2 or will it get only the records in QueryView1 regarding to the where clause from QueryView2?

```
create or replace view QueryView2 as
Select column1
       ...
       columnx
  from SomeIrrelevantView a
  left join QueryView1 b
    on a.Id= b.Id
 where [conditions];

Create or replace view QueryView1 as
select column1
       ...
       columny
 from Table1;
```

Comment: Run a test and see.

Comment: It's tough to guess what the optimization step will do to a query since there are many factors that will be taken into consideration (indexes, statistics, etc). In this case though since there is just a simple select happening against a table, the predicates will almost definitely be pushed down and be applied directly against the table read of `Table1` as opposed to it forming an intermediate result set of `Table1` and THEN applying the predicates.

Comment: Check the execution plan and you will see

Answer (score 3):

> Will it select all records from Table1 in QueryView1 and be filtered in QueryView2 or will it get only the records in QueryView1 regarding to the where clause from QueryView2?

The answer is "either". Oracle will select all the records from `Table1` in `QueryView1` **if** the optimizer thinks that will be most efficient for whatever query against `QueryView2` you've submitted. Similarly, Oracle will evaluate `SomeIrrelevantView` first and the only go to `Table1` for the specific ids needed, if the optimizer thinks *that* will be most efficient.

Oracle will optimize each unique query using all the information available in order to make the most efficient plan.

E.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM QueryView2
```

Oracle's optimizer will consider the tables involved in `SomeIrrelevantView` -- the statistics on those tables and the joins between them -- to estimate how many rows will come out of it.  If that estimate is high, relative to the number of rows in `Table1` ("high" might be a few as 10% of the number of rows in `Table1`), Oracle will likely think it's just faster to `FULL SCAN` of `Table1`.

If your next query is, say

```
SELECT * FROM QueryView2
WHERE some_column BETWEEN 123 AND 456
```

Oracle will again apply its optimization logic.  This time, it might estimate that, with this additional condition, `SomeIrrelevantView` will only output a few rows and so conclude that it should access access `Table1` using an index on `ID` to get the few rows that it needs.

If the query after that is, say,

```
SELECT irrelevant_view_column_a, irrelevant_view_column_b
FROM   QueryView2
```

... and none of the columns you selected are in `Table1` (and none of the "[conditions]" in `QueryView2`'s definition refer to `Table1`), and `Table1.ID` is its primary key, Oracle might conclude that it does not need to access `Table1` at all!

Bottom line: Oracle does its best to optimize each query in its entirety.  Your apparent concern that it will process all the lower level views first is not something you need to worry about too much.